# Should I use get, post, put - does it matter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2, http-verbs

In my app I'm toggling whether a `student` belongs to a `training time` or not when clicking on a time link.

```
# controller
def time
  @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
  @time = TrainingTime.find(params[:training_time_id])
  @student.toggle_time(@time)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @student }
    format.js
  end
end

# routes
resources :students do
  match "time/:training_time_id", to: "students#time", as: :toggle_time
end

# view
<%= link_to t.time_format, student_toggle_time_path(@student, t), remote: true %>
```

Currently it's working using match, but what is the proper way of setting this up and why?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: For general use of http verbs: great answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's all about semantics. `GET` to fetch a resource, `POST` to create a resource, `PUT` (or `PATCH`, these is debate on the matter) to update a resource, `DELETE` to delete one.

To be honnest, there is debate about `POST` and `PUT` too. But since web servers usually only handles `GET` and `POST` (the behavior of other verbs being emulated via parameters), I tend not to bother too much, and stick with what I wrote above.

You don't seem to be creating any resource, so semantically speaking, `PUT` is what you're looking for.

As for `match`, in rails 3.X, is a catch all => all verbs are matched in the route. You can restrain using `match 'something', via: [:get, :post]`. With Rails 4, by default it will do nothing, you have to be explicit about the verbs handled.

Comment: When creating an association like the above, would that be a `POST` or `PUT` - I think its just an update since both objects exist, but maybe that's debatable? Also what does Rail's `match` do? Since in the rake routes it doesn't show anything after it.